# How to print wsdl file data using jsp

Tags: web-services, jsp, servlets, jboss, webserver

In my project we have one **webservice** which contain the data **like date, time, total number of transaction** and all this information i have to print in some other website i am using **JSP** for printing this information but **i don't have idea about how to take data and print the information from webservice** because i am new in this technology please help me.

**this is my data**

```
<asa-details asa-id="1"><dep_txn>6</dep_txn><pre_auth_txn>3936164</pre_auth_txn><pre_bfd_txn>34</pre_bfd_txn><pre_otp_txn>93</pre_otp_txn><prod_auth_txn>505949</prod_auth_txn><prod_bfd_txn>0</prod_bfd_txn><prod_otp_txn>0</prod_otp_txn></asa-details>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the wsimport program in your jdk installation.  This lets you convert a wsdl file to java classes.  (Or use the wsdl2java which comes with cxf)

Next I suggest taking a look at the cxf framework for communicating with the web-service itself: http://cxf.apache.org/

They have really good guides and the framework is well supported.

This framwework will hide all complexity of working with soap envelopes for you.  You are just working with java classes.